# KinematicBody2D direction/rotation towards finger touch in Godot 3

Tags: game-development, godot, touchscreen, godot4, godot3

I've tried a lot to rotate/Direct a kinematicBody2D(Player) in the direction of finger touch. But I wasn't able to do so. Actually, the problem is that in order to move the player there is a need to tap the virtual joystick. So, the player continuosly looks only at the touch on joystick. I'm unable to rotate/Direct it towards the other finger touch.

I tried to use and Area2D on virtual joystick, and then emitting a signal when mouse entered(finger touch) which results in assigning a variable false, which should have resulted in Player not looking towards joystick. But joystick stopped working due to this. Then I tried to use range function to compare the mouse(finger touch) coordinates with a range of coordinates ,i.e., range for x = 400px and so is true for y. But it also didn't worked. I thought I could have used range function incorrectly. But still I doubt this logic to be working. And lastly I tried to move/Direct by using custom actions. Those actions will be produced when joystick will be moved in a specific direction. But it still didn't worked. I was able to use this to rotate Spriteimage but it kept continuosly rotating. And also used a second joystick which also didn't worked as i wasn't able to create ideal logic reauired for it.

Comment: How does your joystick work? I would have expected it stop working (can you elaborate on how it stopped working?), also it might be done in a way that two of it does not work correctly. Checking by an Area2D or making it a Control should work. Barring that, you could track the touch index, but I don't know how easy would that be with your code. Addendum: some versions of Godot had a bug that might result in custom actions getting stuck.

Comment: Actually, that joystick is downloaded from Godot AssetLib. And thanks for telling me that area2d will work. The fault was mine as i didn't wrote a code to turn that variable true, when mouse exited the area. Which was making the if statement false and it stopped working.